# asm drives dissapear after restart

Tags: oracle, storage

here is my story:

I installed on VMWare Oracle Linux 6.6 and now I plan to install grid infrastructure 11.2.0.3 to test database with ASM.
The first I did it was preparing three devices: sdd/sde/sdf. 
I created partition on every drive then I added rule which map UUID to device:

```
[root@ORAHOST dev]# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/95-oracle-asmdevices.rules 
KERNEL=="sdd1", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="36000c29db07df5be78df12f25e0aa7fa", NAME="asm1", OWNER="grid", GROUP="asmadmin", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="sde1", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="36000c29f577daa6a902849d466098de5", NAME="asm2", OWNER="grid", GROUP="asmadmin", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="sdf1", BUS=="scsi", PROGRAM=="/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -d /dev/$parent", RESULT=="36000c29d3ac6ee348f5026a9ac830a62", NAME="asm3", OWNER="grid", GROUP="asmadmin", MODE="0660"
```

and of course /sbin/start_udev restart

Then configuration of oracleasm:

```
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm configure -i 
Configuring the Oracle ASM library driver.

This will configure the on-boot properties of the Oracle ASM library
driver.  The following questions will determine whether the driver is
loaded on boot and what permissions it will have.  The current values
will be shown in brackets ('[]').  Hitting <ENTER> without typing an
answer will keep that current value.  Ctrl-C will abort.

Default user to own the driver interface [grid]: 
Default group to own the driver interface [asmadmin]: 
Start Oracle ASM library driver on boot (y/n) [y]: 
Scan for Oracle ASM disks on boot (y/n) [y]: 
Writing Oracle ASM library driver configuration: done
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm init
Loading module "oracleasm": oracleasm
Configuring "oracleasm" to use device physical block size 
Mounting ASMlib driver filesystem: /dev/oracleasm
```

Finally I added previously prepared devices

```
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm createdisk ASM1 /dev/asm1
Writing disk header: done
Instantiating disk: done
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm createdisk ASM2 /dev/asm2
Writing disk header: done
Instantiating disk: done
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm createdisk ASM3 /dev/asm3
Writing disk header: done
Instantiating disk: done
[root@ORAHOST dev]#
```

result was as below:

```
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm listdisks
ASM1
ASM2
ASM3
```

so everything fine....  until I did a restart. it is enough to restart oracleasm by exit/init and all created disks dissapeares - no more disks anymore :(

```
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm exit
Unmounting ASMlib driver filesystem: /dev/oracleasm
Unloading module "oracleasm": oracleasm
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm init
Loading module "oracleasm": oracleasm
Configuring "oracleasm" to use device physical block size 
Mounting ASMlib driver filesystem: /dev/oracleasm
[root@ORAHOST dev]# oracleasm listdisks
[root@ORAHOST dev]#
```

All advices to such a case found by google are related to multipathing. I have no multipathing - just ordinary virtual devices.  Also permission are often the reason but I don't see any permission faults. 
Could you give me any hints/advices/soultions .

thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if you've only done the exit/init, or have actually restarted the VM? Does `/etc/init.d/oracleasm start` scan for the disks?

Comment: interesting point!  The result of exit/init or restart VM is the same - disks dissapeares but I have just restarted oracleasm using your command ( restart instead of start). Disks are still missing but the new message appears in /var/log/oracleasm:
**oracleasm-read-label: Unable to open device "/dev/fd0": No such device or address**
why oracle search /dev/fd0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Try to put some delay in your asm initialization. Oracle suggests 10 seconds sleep:

```
    echo -n "Initializing the Oracle ASMLib driver: "
    logger "Initializing the Oracle ASMLib driver"
    echo "Sleeping for 10 seconds, waiting for disk discovery to finish"
    logger "Sleeping for 10 seconds, waiting for disk discovery to finish"
    sleep 10
"${ORACLEASM}" init -l "${ORACLE_ASMMANAGER}" -v 1>>/var/log/oracleasm 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The SCSI IDs may not be available to the Linux server on VMWare until you set the `disk.enableUUID` property of your hostname VMX file to `TRUE` in VMWare.